# Mysterious '1' when processing string character-wise

Tags: perl

I'm trying to process the input of a file character per character, but there are some `1`s showing up of which I don't know where they come from. Consider this example:

File `input`

```
First row;
Second row;

Third row;
```

File `test.pl`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open FILE, "<input";

my @characters = split //, join //, <FILE>;
for( @characters ) {
  print $_;
}

close FILE;
```

I would expect this script to only print the content of `input` (though in a pretty complicated way – it's just an example). However, when I run `./test.pl`, I get this output:

```
First row;
1Second row;
1
1Third row;
```

Now my question is: Where do these `1` characters come from?

Comment: Did you try running this in the Perl debugger?

Comment: I didn't know about the debugger before, but googled it now. It wouldn't really have helped me (unless I'm missing something) as I already knew what the problematic line was. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`join //` should be `join ''`.

`//`, short for `$_ =~ m//`, is a match operator. Because it matched successfully, it returned true value `1`.

(`split` is special in that it treats `split /.../` as something similar to `split qr/.../`.)

By the way, always use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have been useful here.

Comment: Thank you! That was tricky – I almost went crazy trying to figure this out. And I'll add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` right away.

Answer (score 7):

According to the perldoc for `join`:

`Beware that unlike split, join doesn't take a pattern as its first argument.`

See more here: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html

Changing the first argument to the literal empty string `""` works as you expect:

```
[ben@lappy ~]$ cat test.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

open FILE, "<input";

my @characters = split //, join "", <FILE>;
for( @characters ) {
  print $_;
}

close FILE;

[ben@lappy ~]$ perl test.pl
First row;
Second row;

Third row;
```

Comment: Thank you. Wish I could accept two answers; the other one was sooner, but both are good in their own way!